# hadoop fs -ls hidden files

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I am writing a utility to clean up HDFS based on a date. While the utility uses hadoop libraries to pull this off, it is also able to be run on a regular file:/// filesystem using either hadoop jar or java -jar to execute it. One shortcoming of the utility that I've found, though, is that it cannot currently clean "hidden" files (preceded with a period). I am guessing, and asking you intelligent people, if that is because HDFS doesn't have hidden files. That assumption validated, is there any suggestion on what I can do to make this an all purpose utility such that it can list and thus delete hidden files?

Comment: Can you show what code you are using for the removal?

Comment: Are you using a Map Reduce job to do this (in which case `FileInputFormat` has a default file filter which removes the hidden files with a period prefix from the `FileInputFormat.listStatus()` method), or a genuine utility? And to reiterate @CharlesMenguy, can you post some code please?

Answer (score -1):

**Command:** *List all hidden Folders and Files*

```
~]$ ls -ld .?*
```